# Delphi VCL to use standard action Paste with Data Generator Adapter

Tags: action, delphi-2010, paste, livebindings

I building a VCL forms application with livebindings. I have several edit boxes and string grids which are binded with several properties of a class. The binding direction is  linkBidirectional.

I also want to implement the standard Paste actions that are build-in in Delphi, so I have a TactionList component in my window.

The adaptor autoedit and autopost properties are both true during the adapter creation.

When I type in a editboxes/grids then the properties are successfully updated.

My problem is that is when  paste to the editbox/grid, the text is changing but the property in the class is not. Thats easy to tell because when I refresh my adapter the text is reverted back to the value before pasting.

It looks like that when I am typing in the editbox/grid then the readonly property of the adapter 'AdapterBindSource.editing' is true, and then the adapter can be posted resulting the change of property, whereas when I am pasting, the property remains false, and the "AdapterBindSource.Post" returns and error.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: I also have another clue if helps: If I paste and then use a keystroke, like back space, then the pasted text is also stored to the property.